# How to know what routes go on between two points?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Ok guys, i'm dealing with this situation in my Android App. I have:

- Two points (origin and destination).
- A set of routes or paths in which can pass a car.

So.. my question is: how can I know what of these routes is the most nearest route from my location (origin) that can take me to another location (destination)?

I neeed to use Google Maps API? What part of the API?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested you can compute the direction between two points. It will not however consider the actual roads but rather the air distance. But I don't think that they are very off. So to sum it up, eite use the google API as suggested or you can use something like the below.

```
public double distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    {
        double theta = lng1 - lng2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        return (dist);
    }}


private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rene..but this could help me if I try to get the time of a travel in one route..I just need to know what is the route that connect the 2 points, or otherwise, the nearest route that can connect me from origin to destination. I just want to know the route.

Comment: Then the only way to go is to use the api from google. Beware that after some requests you will be charged for it. One other solution I thought of is to use predetermined arrays with geolocation with possibles routes but I don't know how big you app is and what ground you are covering there.